# How to add an error handler in NodeJS after all routes defined by user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async-await, middleware

I am writing a library that requires the user to handle errors generated by my library. The way I do it now is that I tell users to add an error handler after all their routes like so:

```js
const app = express();

app.use(MyLibrary.init())

// <user's routes here>

app.use(MyLibrary.errorHandler())

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // user's generic error handler
})
```

The `init` function in my lib is as follows:

```js
function init() {
  return async (request, response, next) => {
    try {
      
      // some logic here that modifies the request object and can throw an error
      
      return next(); // this can also throw an error, or generate an unhandled rejection / error
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  };
}
```

The `errorHandler` function is as follows:

```js
function errorHandler() {
  return async (err, request, response, next) => {
    try {
      if (/*err from MyLibrary*/) {
        // do something and send a response
        return;
      }
      
      next(err);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  };
}
```

**My aim is to make it so that the user doesn't need to add `app.use(MyLibrary.errorHandler())`.**

One solution that comes to mind is that in the `init` function, instead of calling `next(err)`, I can handle my library's error directly. However, errors from `MyLibrary` can also be generated in any of the API handlers that the user writes (since they can interact with my library via the modified `request` object). These API handlers may be `async`.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Good question. Here the helmet middleware have this approach: https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/blob/master/index.ts#L149 Maybe we can inspire of their solution

Comment: @gonzalo I don't think this answers my question. Helmet doesn't seem to require users to handle errors originating from their library. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks